# Unable to launch Sahi in Windows 8

Tags: proxy, sahi

I've been searching everywhere for an answer to this problem. I recently upgraded to Windows 8 and installed Sahi OS in the machine. I had used Sahi before in Windows 7 without any trouble. Now, when I attempt to launch Sahi for any browser, let's say for Firefox:

s/dyn/Driver_initialized?browserType=firefox">http://sahi.example.com/*s*/dyn/Driver_initialized?browserType=firefox

I get a message on the browser that says that the connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

I tried the configure link that would usually take me to:

s/dyn/ConfigureUI">http://localhost:9999/*s*/dyn/ConfigureUI

But once again the browser gives me an error saying the webpage is not available. I already tried to change the proxy settings in the Internet Options so Sahi could listen on localhost port 9999, but nothing seems to work.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Download a trial of Sahi Pro and try to install it. I used Sahi Pro on win 8 and it works perfect. If you can't even run the pro version, then it means that there is a specific problem with Sahi and your config.

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 8 (8.1)
and 
Sahi OS installed from: `install_sahi_v44_20130429.jar`
and Sahi Pro from `install_sahi_pro_v512_20140421.jar`

Check if you have:

1. proper Java version installed (I have jdk1.7.0_02)
2. `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` added to your java cmd line start_dashboard.bat file:

   ```
   java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=%SAHI_USERDATA_DIR_TMP%\config\log.properties -classpath %SAHI_EXT_CLASS_PATH%;%SAHI_CLASS_PATH% -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false net.sf.sahi.ui.Dashboard "%SAHI_HOME%" "%SAHI_USERDATA_DIR_TMP%"
   ```
3. signed ssl certificates for ssl/https webpages - without ssl should work after 1. and 2. steps.